# How to use custom directives with a GraphQL server that uses type-graphql?

Tags: graphql, directive, typegraphql

I've been trying to create a custom directive for a graphql server that uses type-graphql without success. I created a simple example using an uppercase directive (called `upper`).

```
@Directive("directive @upper on FIELD_DEFINITION")
@Resolver()
class HelloResolver {
  @Directive("@upper")
  @Query(() => String)
  hello(): String {
    return "Hello, World!";
  }
}
```

You can see my full unsuccessful (hello not capitalized) type-graphql attempt here:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/immutable-grass-mjjstn

I was able to create and apply this custom directive on a graphql server using SDL.

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  directive @upper on FIELD_DEFINITION

  type Query {
    hello: String @upper
  }
`;
```

Full successful (hello capitalized) SDL implementation here:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/wizardly-breeze-8fq0y4

The type-graphql [documentation on directives](https://typegraphql.com/docs/directives.html) wasn't much help. It references a stale API from `graphql-tools`.

Any idea how to use custom directives with type-graphql using the latest versions of apollo-server and graphql-tools?

Comment: I've created a custom directive using `graphql-tools` (see [graphql-auth-directive](https://github.com/carlocorradini/graphql-auth-directive)). In the examples directory there is an example on how to integrate `type-graphql` (see [this](https://github.com/carlocorradini/graphql-auth-directive/tree/main/examples/typegraphql)). You can get inspired or take it as a starting point for your custom directive.